# How do I get my custom ILogger implementation from ILogger in, for example a controller?

Tags: logging, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, error-logging

I have a custom logger, I would like to create an extension method called

```
SetContext(uniqueKey, object)
```

where I can set a property in my custom logger and log that context when logging a message.

So the code would look like this

```
_logger
     .SetContext(User.Email(), User)
           .LogError(1, new Exception("foo foo foo"), "bleep Bloop");
```

The problem I seem to be facing is that the ILogger, returned via DI in my controller, and in turn used by my extension method is not actually my custom ILogger implementation.

```
 public static ILogger SetContext(this ILogger logger, string uniqueUserIdentifier, object context)
    {
        var redisPublisherLogger = logger as RedisPublisherLogger;

        if (redisPublisherLogger == null)
        {
            return logger;
        }

        redisPublisherLogger.Context = new LoggingContext
        {
            ContextData = context,
            UniqueUserIdentifier = uniqueUserIdentifier
        };

        return logger;
    }
```

So is there anyway I can go about doing something like this, I'm trying to avoid overriding all the logging methods on ILogger.

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 7):

So BeginScope allows you to provide a context for the log...
This link explains it quite nicely...
https://nblumhardt.com/2016/11/ilogger-beginscope/

but an example that I did was:

```
 public static ILogger SetContext(this ILogger logger, string uniqueUserIdentifier, object context)
    {
        var scope = logger.BeginScope(new LoggingContext
        {
            ContextData = context,
            UniqueUserIdentifier = uniqueUserIdentifier
        });

        scope.Dispose();

        return logger;
    }
```

and then in my ILogger implementation I created:

```
private string _loggingContext;
```

and for the BeginScope implementation I did this:

```
  public IDisposable BeginScope<TState>(TState state)
    {
        var s = state as IDisposable;

        _loggingContext = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(s);

        return s;
    }
```

so now I had my specific context data available for use...

Comment: If I use your example, what happens if the logger receives data after the scope is disposed? Does it still have the `_loggingContext` or is a new logger created?

Answer (score 0):

Have a partial answer to your question...

DI returns you an [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Logger](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging/Logger.cs) instance, that is an aggregator for all registered loggers. If you check implementation, you will see that it has

```
public LoggerInformation[] Loggers { get; set; }
```

and it `Log` method iterate over those loggers and calls each separately. Your `RedisPublisherLogger` instance is an item in that array. The problems start here as this `Logger` class is internal and `ILogger` interface doesn't expose that property.

Comment: Thanks, I did notice that, but because it is internal I can't use it.  I'm busy looking into using BeginScope, as it adds context to the log.